# Can I retrobright using Oxycream (used in hair dyes)?

Tags: restoration

The keyboard that I have in [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20181/is-this-keyboard-a-clone-of-ibm-model-m) seems a bit yellow, a classic problem that retrobrighting solves.

[Typical recipes](https://hackaday.com/tag/retrobright/) require UV Light and Hydrogen peroxide. So I wonder if Oxycream can work as well, found in my local stores such as [this](https://www.skroutz.gr/c/2631/galaktomata-energopoiisis-chromatos/f/1088210/oxyzene.html?o=%CE%BF%CE%BE%CF%85%CE%B6%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%B5%20%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B9%CF%89%CE%BD&order_by=pricevat&order_dir=asc) or [this](https://www.miss-sandy.gr/en/professionals/oxycream).

Oxycream is used in hair dyes by professional hairdressers.

Comment: 40 volume creme developer is most often used. Higher or lower concentration of H2O2 just changes the time.

Comment: Just apply Oxycream and let either in a UV Lamp or in a strong sun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8-Bit Guy used Salon Care 40 Volume Creme before he switched to a tub of water and peroxide with UV lights to avoid the risk of uneven results.

The important thing is to check that the active ingredient is high-concentration hydrogen peroxide.

Here's [his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VU7vXMezW_I) on how to do it.

If Oxycream isn't suitable, check places like health food stores, garden stores, pet stores, and pool supply stores.

When I was a kid, you could get 30% food-grade hydrogen peroxide here in Canada to be diluted in water for automatic sprout-growing machines as an algae inhibitor and it's also apparently used that way in other plant- and fish-related uses because, in addition to controlling microbes, highly diluted hydrogen peroxide also helps to oxygenate the water, which helps to prevent root rot, and it just wouldn't be very cost-effective to sell it pre-diluted.