# Should I apply developer cream (Oxycream) using a paint roller instead of a paint brush during retrobriting?

Tags: restoration

As I ask in this [question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20184/22127) an Oxycream is a good approach for retrobriting but due to the dangers of uneven results I was thinking instead of a brush to use a paint roller pin.

The reason I am thinking paint roller is to avoid uneven application of the Oxycream in the plastic surface a similar problem that painting has to faces a well. Therefore a paint roller may solve this problem.

Comment: In my experience, applying the stuff unevenly is not the problem when you achiev wavy or coloudy results. *keeping the suff applied unevenly* is. Just keep spreading and moving the cream during the process constantly (every few minutes)